# Assign Content to Tabs in a Fragment - Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Just created a new project in the newest ADT release in Eclipse and found that it will setup up certain environments for you to get things started.  I choose Tabs + Swipe.

It has this code I have question on:

```
 public static class DummyFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummyFragment () {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}
```

Both tabs refer to this same fragment.  All it does is switch the content on the TextView that has the tab position number on it (1,2, or 3).

1. The more advanced question first:  I want two different Fragments that the tab switches to.  In the example code, it points to the same fragment.  Where does this change take place? and can I see brief code example?
2. Easier question:  I have two pre-defined XML layouts I'd like to set each tab (or Fragment) with.  Do I do this in the actual Fragment? And if so, where?  setContentView does't seem to be working in the onCreateView method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not really sure what this question is asking exactly, but if I understand correctly the `TabHost` (or whatever you are using to manage the `Fragment` tabs) is instantiating multiple instances of the `DummyFragment` and then attaching each to the screen when a tab is clicked. This is all done behind the scenes... all you need to worry about is implementing the `Fragment` and telling the `TabHost` when it should be instantiated/displayed.
2. `Fragment`s don't have a `setContentView` method. You should inflate your `Fragment`'s layout from xml in `onCreateView`. For instance with,

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks, question #2 was answered perfectly.  #1?  I think that was a confusing question.  Maybe you can point me to a good Sample API project that makes use of tabs?